# Размер секций для геометрии THREE.js

Tags: three.js

Можно ли как нибудь изменить размер сегментов для данной фигуры в THREE.js?
[Пример](http://prntscr.com/kbo83r)
Или реализовать данный функционал через определение позиции для Vector3 ? 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajyvyB

```
    // sphere
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
        var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
        var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;
        var object = new THREE.Object3D();
        spherical.set(1000, phi, theta );
        object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );
        vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );
        object.lookAt( vector );
        targets.sphere.push( object );
    }
```

Comment: Размер сегментов зависит от их количества, а так же начальных значений и длин для phi и theta. [документация](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/SphereGeometry) Можно добавить картинку с желаемым результатом? А то из вопроса вообще не ясно - что нужно получить в итоге.

Comment: В итоге требуется вместо сферы реализовать 10-12 угольник пример http://prntscr.com/kbov5j
Как я понял для данного типа геометрии нет высоты и ширины сегментов

Comment: Зато у нас есть `THREE.IcosahedronGeometry()`/`THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry()` (он же - икосаэдр). [Документация](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/IcosahedronGeometry) - в нее иногда полезно заглядывать :)

Comment: Для данного проекта стоит тип рендеринга css3d ( для взаимодействия с dom)  который не принимает геометрию

Comment: По итогу-то что должно получиться? Нужно расставить химические элементы (или любые другие объекты) в формации "икосаэдр", используя `THREE.CSS3DRenderer()`?

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли

Comment: Ну, тут можно только порекомендовать смотреть в [исходный код геометрии икосаэдра](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/IcosahedronGeometry.js) (неважно - буферная или обычная, алгоритм там один и тот же для задания координат вершин) и задавать позиции объектов на основе тамошнего алгоритма.

Comment: На основе векторов? Можно поподробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Или, как вариант, создать геометрию икосаэдра и, перебирая его вершины, назначать их координаты позициям объектов в сцене (например, через метод `.copy()`) - не важно уже будет, какой рендерер при этом используется.

Comment: Можно где-то пример данной реализации посмотреть и что значит (перебирая его вершины) ?

Comment: Простыня наших комментариев становится уж очень длинной. Это не про то, что не хочу помогать - как раз наоборот. Но попробуйте сделать что-то сами :) _"Перебрать вершины"_ - пройтись по ним в цикле `for` или `.forEach()`.